# BroadcastReceiver isn't receiving anything

Tags: java, android, location, broadcastreceiver

I would like to receive information in Application about Enable/Disable Location provider like `NETWORK`, `GPS` etc. I create simple `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class TestReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v("LOCATION_CHANGE_RECEIVER", "PROVIDER UPDATE");
    }
}
```

And register it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
      <application
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:debuggable="true">
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.TestReciver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But when I try switch on/off GPS this `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't receive anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your intent filter to `android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED`

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.TestReciver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```